# Ubuntu 20.04 -- TortoiseHg

Tags: 20.04

It seems like there is no TortoiseHg package available for Ubuntu 20.04.  I was using TortoiseHg with 18.04 without any problem.  What's going on?  It seems like a major issue to me, TortoiseHg is extremely useful.

Comment: has this ever been resolved? I'm also interested in a verion of TortoiseHg for 20.04